# Docker Error: Server Misbehaving

Tags: docker, ucp, docker-engine, docker-ucp, docker-ee

**The details:**

```
Client: Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) 2.0
 Version:       17.06.2-ee-10
 API version:   1.30
 Go version:    go1.8.7
 Git commit:    66261a0
 Built: Fri Apr 27 00:38:41 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server: Docker Enterprise Edition (EE) 2.0
 Engine:
  Version:      17.06.2-ee-10
  API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.8.7
  Git commit:   66261a0
  Built:        Fri Apr 27 00:40:03 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
```

**Kernel Version:**

```
uname -r: 3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
```

**Operating System:**

```
 OS: Red Hat 7.4 (maipo)
```

Docker client was actually unable to connect to Docker Hub to pull the ucp image [[#37532]](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/37532). So we have leveraged `docker save` and `docker load` commands. After untarring the tar file using `docker load`, the ucp image was there.

But we are getting the following error when we run the image:

```
-bash-4.2$ docker container run --rm -it --name ucp   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   docker/ucp:3.0.2 install   --host-address <node-ip-addr> --interactive --registry-username [$REGSITRY_PASSWORD] --registry-password [$REGISTRY_USERNAME]
INFO[0000] Your engine version 17.06.2-ee-10, build 66261a0 (3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64) is compatible with UCP 3.0.2 (736cf3c) 
WARN[0000] Your system uses devicemapper.  We can not accurately detect available storage space.  Please make sure you have at least 3.00 GB available in /var/lib/docker 
Admin Username: admin
Admin Password: 
Confirm Admin Password: 
INFO[0012] Pulling required images... (this may take a while) 
INFO[0012] Pulling docker/ucp-auth:3.0.2                
Please enter your Docker Hub username ([]): ________
Please enter your Docker Hub password (**): 
INFO[0037] Pulling required images... (this may take a while) 
INFO[0037] Pulling docker/ucp-auth:3.0.2                
ERRO[0042] We were unable to pull one or more required images.  Please set REGISTRY_USERNAME and REGISTRY_PASSWORD environment variables for your Docker Hub account on this container with -e flags to run. 
FATA[0042] Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 127.0.0.1:53: server misbehaving 
After referring multiple forums and this article, we had added Google's DNS nameservers.
```

This our resolv.conf file:

```
-bash-4.2$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
#nameserver 127.0.0.1

search 1234.com
nameserver  127.0.0.1
nameserver      xx.xx.xx.xx
nameserver      xx.xx.xx.xx
nameserver     xx.xx.xx.xx
```

The problem is we can't reboot the server because it sits in our corporate DMZ (behind a proxy), and there are other services running too. So, we really can't reboot the server.

We request the community to provide us a solution.

Thanks and Regards
Aditya

Comment: How did you perform the save and load? It seems you docker run command still tries to pull the image (is your loaded image called docker/ucp:3.0.2?

Comment: @lvthillo Actually, this server was unable to connect using docker pull. So I had to do docker save docker/ucp:3.0.2 > ucp.tar on my personal Ubuntu VM. Then I had uploaded it to google drive and shared it with my linux team. They placed the tar file in a server. After which I untarred using docker load --input ucp.tar. Now I could see the image. But when I run the image, the aforementioned output is being displayed. I don't know why it is asking for access to docker hub?

Comment: @lvthillo Should I also save ucp dependency images such as docker/ucp-agent, etc and load them on my server? Will that work?

Comment: I think so yes. Pulling the UCP image triggers a pull of other UCP images (like the auth (where it errors), agent, proxy, etc) + you can also run ucp install with a debug option (--debug). Maybe that provides more info. But I think it's clear that ucp needs to pull other images during its install. (when they aren't stored locally)

Comment: @lvthillo I will try to save and load other dependencies. I will comeback to you on the result. This took 1 week of my time.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part of your error message.
`We can not accurately detect available storage space.  Please make sure you have at least 3.00 GB available in /var/lib/docker`

Try to have more space in /var/lib/docker, mounting other directory / device in this path, with a symlink or whatever that let docker download the image.

Comment: Hi @mulg0r, this is not a space issue, because docker will immediately flash out "hey, ucp image at least needs 3GB memory to spawn a container." I have seen this error and it pops out right at the beginning. This is clearly a DNS resolution issue or I should also save ucp dependency images such as docker/ucp-agent, etc and load them on the server. But I don't know if my prognosis is right or wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're introducing correct login/pass for docker registry?

Comment: Hey @mulg0r, Yes. I am very confident about the username & password combination. The issue is, docker client is unable to contact external world (docker hub) via docker's REST API. This is why I am saving and loading images so that API needn't hit the hub.

Answer (score 0):

@lvthillo

I am answring my own question.

The solution to this problem lies in saving and loading the docker images (including all the sub-dependent images). We had to resort to this method as our servers are behind proxy. The Docker REST API was unable to establish a connection to Docker Hub (outside world). That's why the aforementioned error was surfacing.

The offline method solved our problem. I know it unwieldy, but it is working.

Regards
Aditya

Comment: What is the offline method?