# Unable to connect to Go proxy from Kubernetes cluster with "go mod vendor"

Tags: go, kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

The following error is occurring when `go mod vendor` is run from pod cli in kubernetes cluster.

> Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/google/uuid/@v/v1.1.2.mod":
> dial tcp: lookup proxy.golang.org on XX.X.X.XX:53: server misbehaving

When the same command is run on the command prompt in the same machine, it is downloading the packages.

Comment: Please provide more details about your cluster and what you want to achieve. Its issue with your kubernetes cluster or its more like you want to do something using GO code on cluster?

Comment: I am deploying a Hyperledger Fabric network on a kubernetes cluster that has a master and 2 node machines with Ubuntu OS (not in cloud).To write SmartContracts Go is used. To install the dependencies **go mod vendor** command is used from one of the pods created as part of setup.

Comment: does this look related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51551612/docker-error-server-misbehaving?

Comment: Is this error related to Go chaincode? If so I think you need to run the following command before packaging your chaincode... 

`GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor`

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html?highlight=vendor

If it isn't related to chaincode, could you add more information about your Fabric network and where you're seeing the error.

Comment: The issue is not actually related to Fabric per se.  You have a DNS resolution issue within your Kubernetes cluster.